# Command List for Raspberry Pi Terminal

Tags: raspbian

Is there a list of commands for the Raspberry Pi out there?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. I think that a *list* is only part of the deal and I strongly recommend following some tutorials, e.g. at raspberrypi.org and going through the MagPi journal (free online resource!) - they have a special issue concerning the command line. Last but not least - visit our blog, e.g. the series on [Improving Your Command Line Skills](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141758901139/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-1).

Comment: See a full list of topics on the blog: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/852/piversify-the-community-driven-blog-dedicated-to-the-raspberry-pi?cb=1 and note that repeating blog posts or full tutorials is typically not a good format for StackExchange Q&A.

Answer (score 7):

Just to note, Raspbian is just Debian ported to RPI. I found one useful list here

http://www.improgrammer.net/linux-commands-cheat-sheet/

I am duplicating the contents here in case the link dies

[disclaimer] No copyright infrigment intended.

[image: command list]

Comment: Great list. Just note that _any_ application you install on the RPi (through the Software Center or by using `sudo apt-get install <app-name>`) will have one or more commands that allow you to run it on the command line. So there is no such thing as a complete list of all commands, as new programs keep being added on a daily basis.